# Is it possible to stretch a canvas to fill a div that is sized with display:flex?

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas, flexbox

I have a DOM like so:

```
<div id="container">
    <header>THIS IS MY HEADER</header>
    <div id="content">
        <div>
            <canvas id="canvas" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>THIS IS MY FOOTER</footer>
</div>
```

Styled as a flexbox column with a sticky footer like so:

```
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-height: 100vh;
}

#content {
    flex: 1;
}
```

This produces something like this:

[image: DOM 1.0]

But I can't dimension the canvas to properly fill the appropriate space...

If I run this:

```
context = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext("2d");

var r = context.canvas.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
context.canvas.width = r.width;
context.canvas.height = r.height;

context.fillStyle="red";
context.fillRect(0, 0, context.canvas.width, context.canvas.height);
```

the call to `context.canvas.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect()` returns dimensions of the entire `<body>` (even though the `parentElement` is a `<div>` sized via flexbox), resulting in this:

[image]

As you can see, setting the dimensions of the `<canvas>` too large seems to break the `flexbox` and produce scrollbars etc.  I can understand why this happens, but I can't work out how to get the CORRECT dimensions to send to the canvas.

### EDIT

I have updated the example to include the missing `<div>`.  Also, once I solve this I need to be able to divide the space evenly between 2 or 3 canvases.  Again, this would be easy to do if I could get the dimensions of each canvases parent `<div>` once it has been sized according to the rules of `flexbox`.

Comment: Did you find any error ?

Comment: Umm... no.  No errors.  Just want to dimension the canvas to take up 100% of the space provided by the `content` div inside the flexbox (ie: the space between the grey header and footer).

Answer (score 1):

Set `display:block` to `canvas` element

*Or* `position: absolute;`

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var r = canvas.parentElement.getBoundingClientRect();
canvas.width = r.width;
canvas.height = r.height;

context.fillStyle = "red";
context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
#content {
  flex: 1;
  background: green;
}
canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <header>THIS IS MY HEADER</header>
  <div id="content">
    <canvas id="canvas" />
  </div>
  <footer>THIS IS MY FOOTER</footer>
</div>
```

### [Fiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/rayon_1990/p8vvk2k5/)